# autocomplete in grails 1.3.7

Tags: grails

I am new to grails. I am using grails 1.3.7 version. Now I need to use a autocomplete from a list. But I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone please help me on this ? I really need the help from view to controller. thank you all in advance.

here is my view page below >>>

```
 <%@ page import="com.Login" %>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <resource:autoComplete skin="default" />
</head>

<body>
<g:form>
    <div>
        <label>Autocomplete Box :</label>
        <richui:autoComplete name="allusername" action="${createLinkTo('dir': 'login/allusername')}" />
    </div>
</g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my controller below >>>

```
    package com

    class LoginController {
        def allusername = {
            def logins = Login.findAllByUsernameLike("%${params.query}%")

            //Create XML response
            render(contentType: "text/xml") {
                results() {
                    logins.each { login ->
                        result(){
                            username(login.username)
                            //Optional id which will be available in onItemSelect
                            id(login.id)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: isn't there anybody? I need the help so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same thing in 1.3.7, the simplest way of doing it is to install the Rich UI plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/richui#AutoComplete)

In the documentation you have a more or less complete example that you can use.

Good luck.

Comment: I am going on your following way. I have installed richui. I have written the code you suggest. But it's not working. I have given my view page and controller action. Can it help you to suggest me to do my job?

Comment: My action is being called from view. And the query is retrieving the id of username. But it is not showing the result in the field. Only the dropdown is being yellow color when data found. And the word 'results()','result()','username','id' is underlined in controller. I don't know what is the meaning of underline. Can you please take a look at this ? I think I am so close of it.

Comment: Hi Sumon, did you manage to solve the issue? This is a link that probably will have a lot of useful info: http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Controllers/render.html

Comment: @ marko I want to use the css file for autocomplete field and list of item of my own. I did not understand how to do. Can you please explain ?

Comment: I need to change the css very much

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete requires javascript. Try [jQuery UI.](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

There are alot of examples. What you basicaly need is a controller action/url that will server either JSON or XML as a response to AJAX call from the autocomplete. I also suggest upgrading to a newer version of grails where jQuery comes already included.

Comment: how can I install jquery in my grails application. I have never done it. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing autocomplete requires couple components. one is to allow users to type and send that to the server using ajax. This portion could be handled using lots of javascript libraries for example, jquery autocomplete or if you are using bootstrap typeahead. The other portion is the server lookup or search the value and send the result back to the browser usually in JSON format. I wrote a blog about this a while ago, see if it can help you [here](http://alidadasb.blogspot.com/2011/12/enabling-jquery-autocomplete-with.html)
There are also couple plugins in grails that helps you achieve this as others are suggesting.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to install jquery plugin. But it shows the following message when execute >> "Failed to install plugin [jquery-1.7.1]. Plugin has missing JAR dependencies." Now what can I do for it. I need your suggestion man.

Comment: you probably need to submit another question for that. with the details of the problem and the steps you took for installation.